# How to write a row that is empty to a Table Variable

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following SQL query

```
Declare @EIDDetail Table
 (inc_synopsis varchar(5000),EmployeeName varChar(50),inc_id int, acc_id int
,acc_eid int, inc_event_Number Varchar(12), inc_date_occurred_startdate,acc_afg_id int,
inc_time_occurred_start varchar(8),inc_date_recvd date,inc_date_closed date,inc_is_uof bit,
InvestigatorName VarChar(42),inc_is_comp_via_sup bit,
inc_is_comp_via_psdbit, inc_is_admin_review bit
, inc_comp_is_inquiry bit, inc_comp_is_invest bit, div_name VarChar(50), inc_comp_is_referral bit)

INSERT INTO @EIDDetail SELECT b.inc_synopsis, a.EmployeeName As AccusedName, b.inc_id, a.acc_id, a.acc_eid, 
b.inc_event_number, b.inc_date_occurred_start,  a.acc_afg_id,     b.inc_time_occurred_start, b.inc_date_recvd, b.inc_date_closed, b.inc_is_uof, 
c.InvestigatorName, b.inc_is_comp_via_sup, b.inc_is_comp_via_psd,b.inc_is_admin_review,b.inc_comp_is_inquiry,b.inc_comp_is_invest, d.div_name, 
b.inc_comp_is_referral
FROM dbo.VW_ACCUSED_DISCIPLINABLE_CHARGE AS a INNER JOIN
dbo.Tbl_Incident AS b ON a.acc_inc_id = b.inc_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.VW_INCIDENT_INVESTIGATOR AS c ON b.inc_id = c.inc_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Tbl_Division AS d ON b.inc_inv_div_id = d.div_id
WHERE
a.acc_eid IN (435,35) And (b.inc_comp_is_inquiry = 'False') AND (b.inc_deleted = 'False') OR
a.acc_eid IN (435,35) And(b.inc_deleted = 'False') AND (b.inc_comp_is_invest = 'False') OR
a.acc_eid IN (435,35) And(b.inc_deleted = 'False') AND (b.inc_comp_is_referral = 'False') OR
a.acc_eid IN (435,35) And(b.inc_deleted = 'False') AND (b.inc_is_uof = 'True')

select * from @EIDDetail
```

This works okay until I have a parameter that has no records.  When That Happens I need to include that employee identified by the parameter and show in the record set the employee name and "No Records Found' in my synopsis field.

I can not seem to figure this out.  I have tried using the ISNULL function like this

```
    SELECT ISNULL((SELECT My code above)), (new select here))
```

But that gives me an error message "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Am I heading in the right direction with the ISNUll function or is there any other way to accomplish this

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify - is this a search where you want any employee to return a record, but only populate the fields other than EmployeeName when records are found?

Comment: Let me try and clarify the situation. I have a list of employee ID numbers over 1,400 in this list. I have created a report that uses a multi value parameter that will provide some information on the employees in my list of IDs. The repot will select all of these ID Numbers when it runs. Not all employees in the employee ID list will have data to report on. I have to include those employees, with no data, in my report. Showing the Employee Name and indicating No Records were found. So ISNULL will not work, @@RowCount will not work and I just tried IF EXISTS none seem to work

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like:

```
DECLARE @EIDDetail Table <etc>

INSERT INTO @EIDDetail
 SELECT <etc>

IF @@rowcount = 0
    INSERT INTO @EIDDetail
     SELECT <query designed for "no data available" parameters>
```

Just because it is possible to jam everything into a single query (something I am guilty of myself) doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but that does not work seems that since the parameter in this case has 2 records one of which has data and one that does not the @@RowCount will be greater then 0.

Comment: Reviewing your query closer: try turning the inner join on `dbo.Tbl_Incident` to a left outer join, at which point isnulling all columns from that table should do what you want. Also, your where clause confuses me, should there be parentheses around the sets of `and` clauses that are separated by those three `or`s?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the ISNULL expression, then you have to use it on that one particular field (not a whole select statement).  So, you could have something like:

```
SELECT ISNULL(field1, "Empty") AS field1, ISNULL(field2, "Empty") AS field 2
FROM TableName
```

The above assumes that Field1 and field2 are string-types (e.g., Varchar).

Answer (score 0):

The output of your query then should be a left join or outer apply where your primary table is the list of IDs that you passed in (either in flex parameter or a table variable form), so:

```
SELECT IDs.ID, ISNULL(Records.A, "No Data Available")[, ...n]
FROM @TableOfIDs IDs
    OUTER APPLY (
        <query returning results you are interested in>
        WHERE IDs.ID = InnerIDTable.ID
    ) Records
```

Then, on the report side, make your outputs responsive to the first occurrence of "No Data Available" so that it reformats the output. As the point above is made, ensure that your output from ISNULL is the same type as the column you're selecting.